# JPA persistence.xml not found

Tags: jpa, jdbc

I know this question has been asked before but I still can't get JPA to work with my project.
I am getting the PersistenceException No provider found.
I have the persistence.xml in my src/main/resources/META-INF folder and I am using m2 for building but the persistence file is not moved to the build directory.

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.entities.User</class>
    <class>com.entities.Group</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BandwidthX"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And I am trying to persist using this code:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf =
        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `persistence.xml` should be inside the `src/main/resources/META-INF` folder for the build to work correctly.

See Section 8.2.1 of [the JPA spec](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/).

Comment: Ah, OK. Makes the matter less clear. Could you please list the maven commands you execute and check the contents of the resulting .war file?